# Image file name is not in UTF8 format when I save image through imagejpeg in php

Tags: php, utf-8, image-compression

Here is my code which is not saving image filename in utf8 format in php,

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$data = $_POST ['img'];
$data = str_replace ( 'data:image/png;base64,', '', $data );
$data = base64_decode ( $data );
$meme_filename_in_utf8  = "UTF8 STRING NAME";
$url = UPLOAD_DIR . $meme_filename_in_utf8 . '.jpg';
$source_url = imagecreatefromstring($data);
imagejpeg($source_url, $url, 90);
```

The above code saves image using imagejpeg, but file name is saving as "Ã Â®Â‡Ã Â®Â¨Ã Â¯ÂÃ Â®Â¤-Ã Â®Â®Ã Â®Â¾Ã Â®Â¸Ã Â¯Â.jpg". I need to save image in utf8 format.

Comment: How should the file name actually look like?

Comment: What character encoding was this script files saved in?

Comment: File name actually looks in tamil language it will be in utf8_general_ci @lenz

Comment: Can you show the file name, please?

Comment: File name should be "இந்த மாஸ்டர் என்ன.jpg" but it is looks like Ã Â®Â‡Ã Â®Â¨Ã Â¯ÂÃ Â®Â¤-Ã Â®Â®Ã Â®Â¾Ã Â®Â¸Ã Â¯Â.jpg @lenz

Comment: In a nutshell: it's somewhere between a giant headache and impossible to create specific non-ASCII filenames and you probably don't want to bother with it.

Comment: To me it looks like the file name actually *was* encoded with UTF-8, but the OS is interpreting it with a different codec. I couldn't figure out what codec that would be, though. And deceze is right – it might not be worth the pain.